# HTML onclick handler not triggering innerHTML changes

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

I am making a hunger games simulation and this is my code:

```
console.log(data);
document.getElementById("playarea").innerHTML = data;
console.log(document.getElementById("playarea").innerHTML);
```

When I log the variable `data` to the console it gives me the following result,

```
<img src='img/fight.png'><br />
You grabbed a loaf of bread out of the crate, the girl from 9 comes to you for a fight.
<br />
<button onclick=fight('You grabbed a loaf of bread out of the crate, the girl from 9 
comes to you for a fight.','','',4,1,2)>
Punch in the head
</button><br />
<button onclick=fight('You grabbed a loaf of bread out of the crate, the girl from 9 
comes to you for a fight.','','',4,1,2)>Punch in the chest</button><br />
```

When I log the `innerHTML` of `playarea` I get

```
<img src="img/fight.png"><br>
You grabbed a loaf of bread out of the crate, the girl from 9 comes to you for a fight.
<br>
<button onclick="fight('You" grabbed="" a="" loaf="" of="" bread="" out="" the=""  
crate,="" girl="" from="" 9="" comes="" to="" you="" for="" 
fight.','','',4,1,2)="">
Punch in the head
</button><br>
<button onclick="fight('You" grabbed="" a="" loaf="" of="" bread="" out="" the="" 
crate,="" girl="" from="" 9="" comes="" to="" you="" for=""    
fight.','','',4,1,2)="">
Punch in the chest
</button><br>
```

In the `onclick` it is separating each word and treating them like variables.

How can I make the `innerHTML` to be the same as data variable?

Comment: It is better to use jQuery and forget quotes problems. $("#playarea").html(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change (within data)

```
<button onclick=fight('You grabbed ...','','',4,1,2)>
```

into

```
<button onclick="fight('You grabbed ...','','',4,1,2)">
```

You can only ommit the quotes if the value is just one word.

Comment: +1; this is the answer. To elaborate on this, when you leave out the quotes, the additional words are parsed as attributes of `<button>`, thus the `grabbed="" a=""`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. I had to use both types of quotes inside of a string so i added + ' " ' + inside of the data variable and it works great!